# Counting the occurrences of elements in a set of arrays

Tags: perl

How can I count the occurrences of particular values from arrays?

My Perl code

```
@a  = qw(one two three four);
@b  = qw(one one two four four);
@c  = qw(four two one one);
@d  = qw(four);
@f  = qw(one two);

@ta = ("@a", "@b", "@c", "@d", "@f");
@ar = qw(one two three four);

foreach (@ta) {

   @v = $_;
   @z = map split, @v;

   foreach my $mnz (@ar) {
      @resz = grep { $z[$_] eq $mnz } 0 .. $#z;
      $mz = @resz;
      $zs += $mz;
   }
}

foreach $sx (@ar) {
   print "Total no of $sx is: $zs\n";
}
```

The output I expect is

```
Total no of one is: 6
Total no of two is: 4
Total no of three is: 1
Total no of four is: 5
```

My program works fine if I count only a single value, for example `@ar = qw(one)`. But I want all the outputs at once. How can I do that?

Comment: You perform the addition `+=` on a variable in another for loop. How would you expect it to retain the individual values? You should use a hash for this instead: `$hash{$word}++;` And you should learn to use `use strict; use warnings;` to save yourself some debugging time.

Answer (score 1):

You should `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare every variable using `my` as close as possible to its first point of use. You should also use meaningful variable identifiers. Both of these measures will help your debugging enormously.

You have only *one* count variable `$zs` and so there is no way of keeping separate counts of each of the values once the loops are complete.

You could print each count inside the loop, but you would need to put the first loop *inside* the second one. Here a working example that does this while keeping your basic technique.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a  = qw(one two three four);
my @b  = qw(one one two four four);
my @c  = qw(four two one one);
my @d  = qw(four);
my @f  = qw(one two);

my @ta = ("@a", "@b", "@c", "@d", "@f");
my @ar = qw(one two three four);

for my $mnz (@ar) {

  my $zs;

  for (@ta) {
    my @z = grep { $_ eq $mnz } split;
    $zs += @z;
  }

  print "Total no of $mnz is: $zs\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Total no of one is: 6
Total no of two is: 4
Total no of three is: 1
Total no of four is: 5
```

But that is far from an ideal solution. Whenever you find yourself separating data into categories you should think of using hashes. It's not clear whether you need the `@ta` and `@az` arrays for something apart from this task, but here is a more Perlish way to write the whole thing

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lista = qw(one two three four);
my @listb = qw(one one two four four);
my @listc = qw(four two one one);
my @listd = qw(four);
my @listf = qw(one two);

my @lists = \( @lista, @listb, @listc, @listd, @listf ); 

my %counts;

++$counts{$_} for map @$_, @lists;
print "Total no of $_ is: $counts{$_}\n" for keys %counts;
```

**output**

```
Total no of two is: 4
Total no of four is: 5
Total no of three is: 1
Total no of one is: 6
```

Comment: Thank you Borodin. 'print' give the outputs so why use 'printf' for print the statement?

Comment: @user3902011: Because I started off using `printf` and changed my mind, but forgot to change the call! I've fixed it. Thanks.